# Oracle 10g SQL like using REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g

To extract only the appropriate rows, i have to do something like Mycolum in ('x%','f%') : wich means i want all the rows where Mycolumn is starting with `x` or `f`,

i can use `REGEXP_LIKE(Mycolumn, '^x', 'i')` : to extract all rows where Mycolumn start with `x` how can i add OR in regex to tell to my function i need also rows starting with `f`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Mycolumn, '^[xf]')
```

Comment: because i have numbers as a varchar and when i try REGEXP_LIKE(Mycolumn, '^[67]') i got only those who start with 7

Comment: @archavin: "*because I have numbers as a varchar*". Don't do that. Never store numbers in varchar columns. This is exactly the kind of trouble you get yourself into if you do that.

Comment: it's not my problem, because there are some numbers starting with 0 like 0236 or 0026...i found this Database already created.

Comment: I'm really sorry it was my fault, your solution resolve my problem. because i did this :  after select i restrected the number of rows to show " where rownum < 5 " and it show only rows start with 7 and not 6 because rows who start with 6 are in the botom. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR to provide both the conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN, '^x')
OR REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN, '^f');
```

Answer (score 0):

I love regexes, but you don't need them for this. I would use just normal `LIKE`, which may be faster:

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '[^xfXF]%'
```

`LIKE` also has a more readable syntax, in my opinion at least.